# Move single post to another domain

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engine

I have 3 post on my word press blog (self hosted) and I have 27 post on my new wordpress blog (self hosted).
I want to remove 3 post from old blog and move it on new blog

In this case my domain will change. 
It's effect on copyscape ? both article owned by me i want only move, not much.

Answer (score 0):

**WordPress** has the ability to **export** posts from one blog to another. The export feature is in the **admin dashboard** under `Tools->Export`. Just choose your 3 posts and download the export file. It downloads as an `.xml` which you can then import into your new WordPress site. Tools->Import - WordPress

Comment: Yes i know but i want to know about seo if i remove post from old blog and move it new blog. it is copy ???????
I dont want to lose seo.

Comment: As per my knowledge, If you are deleting it permanently from the old blog then It will not be consider as a copy.Just make sure that you are not keeping any part of that post in to an old blog.

Comment: Yes it's good. and what about 404 not found ?
May i use 301 redirct for it ?

Comment: Yes you can !
But you should keep in mind about SEO .

Comment: I post this question because i'm not seo expert. I want to move 3 post without lose seo or get panelty by google panda.

Comment: See If you do complete replication of all URLs it should not be affected at all.So By using 301 redirect, it will transfer almost all **link juice**(rank power). So I don't think you will lose you SEO in that.